# Selenium WebDriverException: Message: address not available, when running Django test on jenkins server

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, django, jenkins, selenium

I have running docker an AWS EC2 instance. Using docker-compose, I have jenkins running in one container. I have a jenkins pipeline which checks out my repo ( which is a Djano application, with a docker file ). My pipeline then builds the docker image using the Docker file. This is build on the host docker daemon as I have mapped these volumes in my docker-compose file

```
volumes:
   - /var/run/docker.sock : /var/run/docker.sock
```

The image is built successfully, and I can run commands in this image from my jenkins pipeline using

```
img = docker.build(....)
img.inside{
    sh '.....'
}
```

But when I try to run my Django tests using

```
img.inside{
   sh 'python manage.py test'
}
```

Tests which inherit from TestCase run successfully. But I have tests which are subsets of StaticLiverServerTestCase, they use selenium. I get an error when trying to initialize my Webdriver instance:

```
browser = WebDriver()

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: address not available.
```

These tests run successfully on the exact same setup on my local machine

```
docker-compose run web python manage.py test
```

My guess is that it could be something wrong with AWS security groups and port access. The LiveServerTestCase might by trying to use a port which the AWS security group does not allow. But I tried enabling TCP access to all ports from internal traffic, but this also does not work.

Please has anyone encountered any similar problems or has any tips for me.